# android - ListActivity and ListView

Tags: android

I'm new to android programming.

I get the error on extending my `Activity` from `ListActivity` on the line

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Using the `Log.e()` in a try/catch the LogCat says:

> 12-25 05:58:36.959: E/ERROR(657): ERROR IN CODE: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Listview

My main.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Listview
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asd"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code of the activity:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class StatusListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR",e.toString());    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should rename your class ListActivity. However, it is better to provide us with code of the activity that corresponds to this layout file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code and error message shows Listview with a small 'v'.  Should be ListView with a capital 'V'.

Comment: NOT "stupid".  Even experienced programmers sometimes cannot see a bug though looking right at it.  That's why there are forums like Stack Overflow!

Comment: You may find it easier to use the layout designer in ADT for Eclipse rather than hand-coding UI ... it avoids they types of inscrutable errors. Always keep up to date at http://tools.android.com